# How to connect MySQL database? this code base,there were no erors. But can not insert data

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

public String connectionString = @"server=localhost;port=3306;user id=root;database=Product;persistsecurityinfo=True;password=xxxxxx@;";


protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection mySqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        using (mySqlCon)
        {
            mySqlCon.Open();

            MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("Proc_Store_Products", mySqlCon);
            mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_productId", Convert.ToInt32(hfProductID.Value == "" ? "0" : hfProductID.Value));
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_productCode", txtproductCode.Text.Trim());
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_productName", txtproductName.Text.Trim());
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_price", Convert.ToDecimal(txtprice.Text.Trim()));
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_description", txtdescription.Text.Trim());

            mySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            clear();
            lblSuccessMsg.Text = "Submitted Successfully";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

This is the SP code

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE Proc_Store_Products(
    _productId int, 
    _productCode varchar(20), 
    _productName varchar(40), 
    _price decimal(18,2), 
    _stock int, 
    _description varchar(200)
) BEGIN
IF _productId = 0 then
    INSERT INTO productInfo(productCode,productName,price,stock,description) 
    VALUES(_productCode,_productName,_price,_stock,_description);

else
    UPDATE productInfo
    SET
    productCode = _productCode,
    productName = _productName,
    price = _price,
    stock = _stock,
    description = _description
    WHERE
    productId = _productId;

END IF;
END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong here. Could you show the code of the stored procedure? Are you sure about the no error displayed? Did you follow the flow of the code with the debugger?

Comment: Yes..no errors..below one is the stored procedure

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Well, you have 6 parameters expected in the SP, but you pass just 5 parameters. Where is the parameter for the Stock value? It seems strange that you don't have any kind of errors when you try to execute this code. As explained, I really suggest to follow your code with the debugger. Something is not as it seems

Comment: Side note: [edit] your question to add informations. Do not post an ANSWER to add the SP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from productinfoProc_Store_ProductsDELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Proc_Store_Products`(

_productId int,
_productCode varchar(20),
_productName varchar(40),
_price decimal(18,2),
_stock int,
_description varchar(200)

)
BEGIN

    IF _productId = 0 then
        INSERT INTO productInfo(productCode,productName,price,stock,description) 
        VALUES(_productCode,_productName,_price,_stock,_description);

    else
        UPDATE productInfo
        SET
        productCode = _productCode,
        productName = _productName,
        price = _price,
        stock = _stock,
        description = _description
        WHERE
        productId = _productId;

    END IF;



END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please put that in your question text, not as an answer!